# List of the dates between two dates from another table

Tags: powerquery

I created the list of the dates between two dates (minimum and maximum) from another table where i compare the max date and today.

```
let
  first = List.Min(#"Mizan (Banka&Kasa)"[Tarih]),
  last = List.Max(
{(List.Max(#"Mizan (Banka&Kasa)"[Tarih])), Date.From(DateTime.LocalNow())}
),
howmanydays = Number.From(last) - Number.From(first) + 1,
Source = List.Dates(first, howmanydays, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))
in
Source
```

But I am sure there must be an easier way to achieve this list.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats pretty much it, unless you prefer to omit howmanydays and use

```
Source = {Number.From(first) .. Number.From(last)}
```

then expand and convert format to date

Comment: thanks @horseyride . r u sure about the Source syntax ? it didnt like it... expression error...

Comment: it seems they do not return numbers but dates...  **We cannot apply operator .. to types Date and Date.**

Comment: **Source = {Number.From(first) .. Number.From(last)},**

Comment: you are correct. fixed above

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a table with the dates of another table maybe the best is:

```
CREATE NEW TABLE
date = CALENDAR(maxx(table_name, table_name[Date]),TODAY())
```

- **`table_name`** is the table you want to select
- **`table_name[Date]`** is the cell you want to get the last date

Comment: it’s a power query question, not pbi